# C - Copy a String without a library function

Tags: arrays, c, copy, c-strings, function-definition

I want to create a function that takes a string literal and an array and copies the characters of string literal to the array. Could you please inform me what is the issue in the following code ?
The output of this code is just a capital D with some whitespaces ("    D") so i think a random location is accessed somehow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Function Prototypes:
    void CopyAString(const char * s1, char s2[]);
    
    // Initialize the string literal str1 and an array s2 of size 12.
    const char *str1 = "Hello World";
    char s2[12];
    // In the function i pass the address of str1 and the array s2.
    CopyAString( &str1, s2 );

    for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++){
        printf("%c", s2[i]);
    }

}

void CopyAString(const char * s1, char s2[])
{
    const char * p1 = s1;
    int index = 0;

    while (*p1 != '\0') {
        s2[index] = *p1;
        index++;
        p1++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to write the NUL terminator `'\0'` into the string. Aside, it would be better to sequence the arguments the same way round as the standard library function `strcpy()`.

Comment: You are also calling the function incorrectly with `CopyAString( &str1, s2 );` as the compiler will warn. Please turn on compiler warnings. Aside: you are outputting one too many characters (which is beyond the array bounds).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, the NULL terminator is placed automatically by the compiler after the assignment const char *str1 = "Hello World";

Comment: No, you stop at that one without copying it.

Comment: The compiler will put a NUL-terminator at the end of the string `str1` points to. That's true. However, **you** are responsible for writing the data to the array `s2[]`. The compiler cannot know if your function `CopyAString` intentionally does not place a NUL-character there. There are cases where a NUL-character is not wanted...

Comment: It is very clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your program has two bugs:

### First

Your function `CopyAString` does not write a `'\0'` character to the end of the string. This means that the string `s2[]` does not have a `'\0'` character and you would not be able to pass `s2[]` to functions like `printf()` or other functions that expect an "input" string to end with `'\0'`.

However, in your program, this is not a problem because the `for` loop expects a fixed-length string.

### Second

In your program, the following problem is more important:

You pass `&str` as first argument to `CopyAString` instead of `str`.

This means that `s1` (the first argument of `CopyAString`) does not point to the character `'H'` of `"Hello world"` but it points to the first byte of the value stored in the variable `str`...

Note that the variable `str` is a pointer: It does not store a "value" (here: the string `"Hello world"`) but it stores an address of a value!

If the string `"Hello world"` is stored in the RAM at address `0x20 44 00 40` (this means: `0x40004420` on an x86 or ARM computer or `0x20440040` on a PowerPC), the variable `str` will contain the value `0x20 44 00 40`.

`s1[0]` will be `0x20` (which is the space character). `s1[1]` will be `0x44` (which is `'D'`)...

Comment: At **First** you say there's not a problem, but there *is* UB. The 12th character in `s2` is never initialised, and thus the program can output anything as the 12th character.

Comment: No words to thank you for your detailed explanation!

Comment: @Cheatah Ok. You are right: The loop should run until 10 instead of 11. However, passing `'\0'` to `putchar()` is probably also not what the OP wants...

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should declare the function like

```
char * CopyAString( char *s1, const char *s2 );
```

similarly to the standard string function `strcpy`.

In this function call

```
CopyAString( &str1, s2 );
```

the expression `&str1` has the type `const char **` and yields the address of the pointer `str1` but the function expects an argument expression of the type `const char *` that points to the first element of a string (the string literal).

Within the function you are not copying the terminating zero character

```
while (*p1 != '\0') {
    s2[index] = *p1;
    index++;
    p1++;
}
```

So the destination character array in general will not contain a string.

The function can be defined the following way

```
char * CopyAString( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    for ( char *p = s1; ( *p++ = *s2++ ); );

    return s1;
}
```

Within main instead of this for loop with the magic number 12 in the condition that invokes undefined behavior

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++){
    printf("%c", s2[i]);
}
```

it is better to write

```
for ( char *p = s2; *p != '\0'; ++p ){
    printf("%c", *p );
} 
putchar( '\n' );
```